# Counting experience in Months - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that will count experience based on 2 variables: startDate, EndDate that has following format:

```
First position:  2013-12-01 to 2015-12-01
First position:  2014-12-01 to 2015-05-01 
First position:  2007-07-01 to 2011-10-01
```

Right now I am wondering how to actually achieve that and it is a little bit tricky for me, because I need tell somehow how to actually counts the months, how many mounths got 1 years (12) and do proper math but I don't know how to do it good way with Javascript

I could transfer variables startDate, endDate to have only YEAR-MONTH and then write some logic that will count the experience in Months or maybe there is any library that could help with that?

Here is the code that I write so far

```
async function dupa(){

fileToCurate.forEach(candidate => {
    candidate.folder.forEach(folder => {

        function countFirstExp(firstExperienceStartDate, firstExperienceEndDate){
            // assign variables From, To and count experience
            var firstExperienceStartDate = folder.positions[0].from;
            var firstExperienceEndDate = folder.positions[0].to;            
            
            // if startDate or endDate is not null we can count exp
            if(firstExperienceStartDate !== null && firstExperienceEndDate !== null){
                
                let startDate = firstExperienceStartDate['$date'].substr(0, 10)
                let endDate = firstExperienceEndDate['$date'].substr(0, 10)
                console.log("First position: ", startDate, "to", endDate)
            }
        }
        countFirstExp();
        
        //console.log(candidate.folder)
    });
     //console.log(candidate);
});
```

}

Comment: @caramba the problem is that the variables startDate, endDate are actually strings so I'm not sure

Comment: Parse the strings as dates then?

Comment: I will give a try @Adrian thank you

Comment: `Date.parse("2013-12-01")` @johnsmith

Comment: [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks guys this is a very handy and this what I've been looking for, 1 more question because I'm getting unix time, is there any method that convert the unix timestamp to days?

Comment: To get days from unix timestamp, you first have to multiply the timestamp by 1000 to get milliseconds: `days = ((unix_timestamp * 1000) / (60*60*24*1000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let from = new Date('2007-07-01')
let to = new Date('2011-10-01')

// difference in miliseconds
const difference =  new Date(to - from).getTime() 

// aprrox value of month in seconds
const monthInmiliseconds = 2590000000 


console.log( 'experience :', Math.floor(difference / monthInmiliseconds), 'months')
```